# Probability that, with six girls and six boys in a row, all the girls sit together?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Six boys and six girls sit in a row randomly. Find the probability that six girls sit together?

(a)$\frac{1}{32} (b)\frac{2}{7}$

(c)$\frac{5}{12}$ (d) *None of these*

**what i have tried**

Since six girls need to sit together so the number of combination of girls sitting next to each can be formed =$12 \choose 6$=924
The number arrangement that can be done to make boys and girls sit on $12$ seats= $2^{12}$

Therefore the probability of girls sitting next to each other=$\frac{12 \choose 6}{2^{12}}=\frac{231}{1024}$

But i think so this is not one of the option and so please help me with the problem.

Comment: There are $\binom{12}{6}$ equally likely ways to choose $6$ seats and put "Reserved for Girls" signs on them. How many choices are *favourable* (all the chosen seats are together)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the $6$ girls as one person, then the total number of situations when $6$ girls sitting together is $7!$ multiplied by the permutations of girls $6!$, the total number of all permutations is $12!$, hence the probability is
$\frac{6!7!}{12!}=\frac{1}{132}$.

Comment: but the answer given in solution is $\frac{1}{32}$

Comment: @CY5 This is probably a typo. If you're not convinced, here is a solution on a random book I found on google https://books.google.de/books?id=DoqIu7L2Yg8C&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=ix+boys+and+six+girls+sit+in+a+row+randomly.+Find+the+probability+that+six+girls+sit+together&source=bl&ots=Hbbc8Z06QH&sig=b-FkVxPWBczSTSrmLJSosm5eVdw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TArUVLiaPM7-aPi-gpAD&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=ix%20boys%20and%20six%20girls%20sit%20in%20a%20row%20randomly.%20Find%20the%20probability%20that%20six%20girls%20sit%20together&f=false

Answer (score 2):

The total cases will be $n(s)=12!$.
To find the favourable cases, we assume the group of girls to be a single object and find their permutations. This is given by $7!\cdot 6!$. The first term represents their permutations with the boys and the second represents the permutations among themselves.
Hence, total answer will be given by $$\frac{7!\cdot 6!}{12!}=\frac{1}{132}$$
Hence the answer is **(D)**